# Bolded inline text in HTML emails pushed to new line in Outlook

Tags: html, email, outlook, line-breaks

I've been coming across this issue with HTML emails in Outlook (imported AND copied/pasted into Outlook)...

When there's a bolded word in a sentence, if the line were to break naturally at/right before the bolded word, the word **before** it and the bolded word itself get pushed to the next line. There's ALWAYS room for the word before to be on the line before, and if I remove the bolding, it works as expected (i.e. breaking normally).

I've tried using strong and just b to bold the words, because clearly it has something to do with that styling, but neither make any difference. Changing word-break does seem to do anything either.

Has anyone experienced this before and/or found a solution? Super frustrating and dumb issue.

Here's my code:

```
<ul style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 22px; color: #646464;">
<li>Review the Pension plan and Retirement savings plan <strong>summaries</strong> for complete details about our pension plan.</li>
<li>Watch a retirement planning <strong>seminar</strong> recording (right from the homepage) for a 1.5-hour crash course on our pension plan.</li>
</ul>
```

And here's a visual of what's happening:
[image: Example of word breaking]

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out (of course, 5 minutes after I posted the question), so I'll post here for anyone else to come across, and my future self who will forget what I did.

I added:

```
white-space: pre-wrap
```

to the li tag. The issue was happening with a normal paragraph as well, and I added it to the p tag (rather than the strong/b tag).